# CardView class "could not be found" despite implementing it in the gradle file

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-cardview

For some reason, my CardView cannot find the class.  I'm using it as the root layout and I have implemented it in the gradle file.  I tried all the tips on SO but nothing works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username_display" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password_display" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the complete Gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozbek.cryptpass"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha4'
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `cardView` doesn't show because there is nothing to show since you are setting its `height="wrap_content"` and the only children is empty , try to set your `cardView` height to `60dp` to see if it will show something

```
    android:layout_height="60dp"
```

**edit**

as i can notice in your edit you are using `androidx` so you should use this :

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.1.0'
```

and in your xml file :

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

if you want to use the old classes : add `android:enableJetifier=true` to your `gradle.properties` and use the `appcompat` dependencies instead.

Comment: That isn't the problem.  The problem is that the class could not be found, despite setting it in the gradle file.

Comment: And that's an issue.  How can the class not be found?

Comment: are you sure you added your dependecies into the correct build.gradle file ?

Comment: did you rebuild your project after you add that dependencie ?

Comment: Yes.  I invalidated caches and then rebuilt it.

Comment: could you please post your build.gradle(module:app)

Comment: I've accepted your answer and gave you an upvote.  If you think that this question was well asked, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: No problem my friend :)